# SUPEE-10975 Creates Console Errors

Tags: magento-1.9, patches

Magento Community Version 1.9.0.1
Patched Up till 10888

I just applied patch SUPEE-10975 and now when I go to the checkout pages I am getting some serious console errors:

```
prototype.js:5653 Uncaught TypeError: element.attachEvent is not a function
    at Function.observe (prototype.js:5653)
    at js.js:627
observe @ prototype.js:5653
(anonymous) @ js.js:627
prototype.js:5644 Uncaught TypeError: element.attachEvent is not a function
    at observe (prototype.js:5644)
    at HTMLDocument._methodized [as observe] (prototype.js:438)
    at captcha.js:1
observe @ prototype.js:5644
_methodized @ prototype.js:438
(anonymous) @ captcha.js:1
prototype.js:5644 Uncaught TypeError: element.attachEvent is not a function
    at observe (prototype.js:5644)
    at HTMLDocument._methodized [as observe] (prototype.js:438)
    at common.js:300
observe @ prototype.js:5644
_methodized @ prototype.js:438
(anonymous) @ common.js:300
prototype.js:5653 Uncaught TypeError: element.attachEvent is not a function
    at observe (prototype.js:5653)
    at HTMLDocument._methodized [as observe] (prototype.js:438)
    at livepipe.js:133
    at livepipe.js:135
observe @ prototype.js:5653
_methodized @ prototype.js:438
(anonymous) @ livepipe.js:133
(anonymous) @ livepipe.js:135
window.js:87 Uncaught Control.Window requires IframeShim to be loaded.
(anonymous) @ window.js:87
```

I assume it has to do with the inclusion of the newer version of jquery 1.12.1

But not sure what to do?
I've reverted it and not getting these errors anymore.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Did you tried noConflict after jQuery load?

Comment: I have an uncustomised magento with only a few plug ins.
So I do not want to go around changing the code.

What would noConflict do to resolve this issue?

Comment: No one else is having this problem?

Comment: This is related to conflict with jquery and prototype

Comment: jQuery no conflict should work.